# sort a table with special characters in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, sorting, angularjs-orderby

How can I sort an object based on a property when that property contains special characters such as ä,ü,ö in angularjs using orderBy?

For example if I sort the object users based on the name property,

```
$scope.users = [
 {name:'A', value:'1'},
 {name:'B', value:'2'},
 {name:'Ä', value:'3'},
 {name:'Ü', value:'4'},
 {name:'U', value:'5'}
];
```

it should return:

```
{name:'A', value:'1'},
{name:'Ä', value:'3'},
{name:'B', value:'2'},
{name:'U', value:'5'},
{name:'Ü', value:'4'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort order is determined doing a [lexicographical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) sort by comparing Unicode (**z**: U+005A comes before **e**: U+0065). 
Have a look at this [article](http://www.janholinka.net/Blog/Article/8) which presents two different solutions to your problem.

Comment: nice, actually I read this article before but I didn't look carefully the xecond solution which is really nice. thanks!